# Incompatibility Problem: React Dependency Issue with Material-UI (Mui)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, material-ui

I'm installing react dependencies by `npm i` in [netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) but it seems that there are missing or unresolved libs in material-ui.

Can some help with correct versions ?

```
1:48:24 PM: Failed during stage "Install dependencies": dependency_installation script returned non-zero exit code: 1
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR!
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR! While resolving: @mui/styles@5.15.1
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.11.3
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR!     @emotion/react@"^11.11.1" from the root project
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.11.0
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR!       @emotion/styled@"^11.11.0" from the root project
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR!       3 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system)
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR!     3 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system)
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR!   18 more (@emotion/styled, ...)
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR!
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/styles@5.15.1
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/styles
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR!   @mui/styles@"^5.15.1" from the root project
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR!
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/styles@5.15.1
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/styles
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR!     @mui/styles@"^5.15.1" from the root project
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR!
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
1:48:24 PM: npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `@mui/styles` is not compatible with React 18. If you look at the [`@mui/styles` documentation](https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/) you'll see the following warning message:

> `@mui/styles` was deprecated with the release of MUI Core v5 in late
> 2021. It depended on [JSS](https://cssinjs.org/) as a styling solution, which is no longer used in `@mui/material`.
>
> `@mui/styles` is not compatible with [React.StrictMode](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode) or React 18, and
> it will not be updated.
>
> This documentation remains here for those working on legacy projects,
> but we **strongly discourage** you from using `@mui/styles` when creating a
> new app with Material UI—you *will* face unresolvable dependency issues.
>
> Please use [`@mui/system`](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/) instead.

To make your app compatible with React 18 you'll have to remove the `@mui/styles` dependency from you `package.json` file. Then update the code that is using this dependency to use another styling library, for example [`@mui/system`](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/) or [`@emotion/styled`](https://emotion.sh/docs/styled) which is already in your `package.json` file according to the error message. It is also the default way to style components if you follow the [`@mui/material` installation guide](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/).

---

If you find the above to be to much work at once, you could also downgrade your React version from 18 down to 17 in your `package.json` file as a temporary solution, while you convert your components to use another styling library.